# FAQ autolink on meta points to SO

Tags: discussion, comments, hyperlinks, auto-linking

Since this is only evident in a comment, I'll post a comment under this question. [FAQ] should direct you to the current site's FAQ.

*EDIT:* Now a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to have `[faq]` default to current site's FAQ, and `[meta-faq]` always point to the meta FAQ for both the actual site and its meta. I'm not particularly fussed either way but it seems the more logical way for a default "faq" link to work.

*EDIT 2:* Actually, now that I think about it, it'd be hard to pick a syntax for linking to the normal site FAQ which applies to all sites (e.g you'd have to start using `[so-faq]`, `[sf-faq]` or simlar styles). So I'm happy to concede this one. Retagged as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).

Apologies for having a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) which turned into a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) which turned into a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).

Comment: See the [FAQ] for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `[meta-faq]`, similar to using `[meta-tag:sometag]`. Things on meta get abbreviated with `meta-`.

Comment: `[meta-faq]` produces: [meta-faq]

Comment: That's nice to know and all, but.. *really?* Do we really want `[faq]` to not point to the faq of the site the comment is posted on? I'm happy to have no as an answer, but this just turned into a [feature-request].

Comment: Not really. The meta site is *about* the main site, and the FAQ's for each are different. Users should be able to quickly link to *either* FAQ, and the current syntax is the most straightforward and logical way to do it as it matches the rest of the syntax for automated things.

Comment: +1 I agree it's straightforward, but since it's not obvious that autolinking even exists, I would opt for the most logical default behaviour. Which is that `[faq]` is equivalent to clicking the "faq" button at the top of the page.